# Newly edited pdfs not updating or replacing old pdf in Sharepoint Library

Tags: 2010, document-library, pdf, check-out, check-in

I'm trying to upload and overwrite existing pdfs in my sharepoint library (using sharepoint 2010) but I can't seem to view the "newer" document after editing the "older" document in adobe acrobat 5.

I can check out & open the pdf, but when I make changes to the pdf (like highlights) save and check in the document, the unedited "old" file always opens while the revised pdf never opens.

I've worked around this by deleting the old file, clearing the recycle bin, and then reuploading the revised pdf with a slightly different name (if the new file has the same name as the old file, the old file replaces the new file, instead of the reverse).

I'm getting pretty tired doing this workaround... Does anyone know what's wrong and how to fix this?

Comment: when you upload the new pdf with the same name does the new pdf appears in the version history? if you have the new version in the history, you can pick the new version and open it from  the history?

Comment: I can view the "new" version and open it from the version history, but I've also been sharing links to the document with other users. For some reason the links do not update either.

Comment: I figured out that my problem was being caused by Adobe Reader. 
When I checkout, open, edit, & then try to checkin my changes, SharePoint does the above and doesn't retain my changes (unless I look in the version history). For the future I'll avoid checking out pdfs, and instead work on the edits outside of sharepoint and then upload & replace the existing version.